# `ng-repeat` - directive for `$scope` array length with keeping `html` template

Tags: javascript, angularjs

in my app, i have the `html` template nested in page. I require to use the same template for other `array` of elements.

and the `directive` should works as usual. **In my case `link` method is not called.**

Please any one guide me for correct approach to get this out.

here is my html :

```
<div class="content" ng-controller="main">
      <span class="dgt" ng-repeat="digitDispaly in digitalArray"> //repating
        <span class="sr"> 
          <span>0</span>
          <span>1</span>
          <span>2</span>
          <span>3</span>
          <span>4</span>
          <span>5</span>
          <span>6</span>
          <span>7</span>
          <span>8</span>
          <span>9</span>
        </span>
        <span class="fl"></span>
      </span>
      <span class="line">Line</span>
    </div>
```

js :

```
angular.module('myApp', [])
  .controller("main", function($scope) {
    $scope.digitalArray = ["3", "2", "7"];
  });

angular.module("myApp")
  .directive("digitDispaly", function () {
      return {
        restrict : "E",
        link : function (scope, element, attrs) {
          console.log("hi")
        }
      }

  })
```

[Live Demo](http://plnkr.co/edit/F30xeU?p=preview)

Comment: but you not use your directive. when you use `restrict : "E",` so for using directive you need write something like `<digit-dispaly></digit-dispaly>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You Can  also use it as  class as shown below

http://plnkr.co/edit/eCCVW8obKdCNvKKGmd9S?p=preview

```
 <span class="dgt digitDispaly " ng-repeat="digitDispaly in digitalArray">     //repating

   angular.module("myApp")
   .directive("digitDispaly", function () {
      return {
       restrict : "C",
       link : function (scope, element, attrs) {
       console.log("hi")
      }
    }

 })
```

Comment: It is recommended not to do this and to use only attribute and element directives for future compatibility (and readability, as classes are not meant to invoke behaviour)

Comment: Yes, I agree. is this only applicable for `class` can't i use like data-name ='digitDispaly' ?

Answer (score 0):

It's because you have used

```
restrict : "E",
```

Which means that your directive is applied only on element tags. Like this:

```
<digit-dispaly></digit-dispaly>
```

Your updated plunkr: http://plnkr.co/edit/Kaq2MtYcVTLZsNalNbAm?p=preview

I'd suggest reading a bit about directives: https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive

Comment: Consider pulling the changed parts of the code into your answer instead of just in the plunkr, so that your answer keeps being useful even when the plunkr link is dead